# How to run Windows IIS on top of an ASGI server like hypercorn or uvicorn?

Tags: python, iis, uvicorn, asgi, hypercorn

I have an api based web application written in python using [FastApi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) which uses [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) or [Hypercorn](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/) for deployment.These both are ASGI based servers. Is there a way to run IIS on top of this ?

Comment: Were you able to do that? or is it even possible?

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler is there for Python web apps, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292991/running-fastapi-under-iis

Answer (score 5):

You can defintely run via IIS.  Here is the two possible options you have (I use Hypercorn):

1. HTTPPlaformHandler

   ```
   <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
               <rules>
                   <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                       <match url="(.*)" />
                       <conditions>
                           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                       </conditions>
                       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                   </rule>
               </rules>
           </rewrite>
           <handlers>
               <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
           </handlers>
           <httpPlatform requestTimeout="00:05:00" startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\python-stdout" processPath="[PATH TO YOUR PYTHON EXE]" arguments="-m hypercorn app.main:app -b 127.0.0.1:%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% --keep-alive 5 --worker-class asyncio --workers 9">
               <environmentVariables>
                   <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
               </environmentVariables>
           </httpPlatform>
       </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. AspNetCoreModuleV2 (If you use this one you will have to have a config.py to correctly bind the URL and port.)

   ```
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="[PATH TO PYTHON EXE]" arguments="-m hypercorn app.main:app --config file:config.py" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" requestTimeout="00:26:00" /></system.webServer>   </location><system.webServer></system.webServer> </configuration>
   ```

Comment: pls also share the config.py file

Comment: Is there any way to trim the prefix sent to fastapi if the app is hosted in a virtual directory? I already got the app running, but it can't resolve the right route. Apparently you can't use the rewrite module to rewrite the path requested from browser/client to the fastapi. Do I really have to hardcode the prefix in my app?