# Is there a way to deploy FastAPI on IIS server?

Tags: python-3.x, iis, deployment, fastcgi, fastapi

I'm having trouble deploying a FastAPI app on IIS.

This is the error that I get.

```
Error occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 847, in main
        result = handler(record.params, response.start)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use HttpPlatformHandler, not `wfastcgi.py` please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler

Comment: If you want to run FastAPI in IIS, we can use IIS as a reverse proxy to run FastAPI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: In my opinion you likes me, please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292991/running-fastapi-under-iis/71126359#71126359

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by

1- in cmd pip install a2wsgi

2- in main.py

- A - `from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware`
- B - in the end of your code write

wsgi_app = ASGIMiddleware(app)

like this

```
from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def view():
    return {"Hello":"World!"}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

```
wsgi_app = ASGIMiddleware(app)
```

3- in webconfig add

```
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="main.wsgi_app" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Deploying a FastAPI app on IIS using [HttpPlatform handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler)

The below solution assumes that your fast api application has a virtual environment created using `python -m venv venv` in the root directory of the app. I used **uvicorn** but similar arguments would be used for *hypercorn*.

web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="fastapi_app_handler" 
        path="*" 
        verb="*" 
        modules="httpPlatformHandler" 
        scriptProcessor="C:\fastapi_app\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\fastapi_app\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
    arguments="-m uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" 
    stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\fastapi_app\iis_logs\python-stdout.log">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
```

main.py

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    a = "a"
    b = "b" + a
    return {"hello world": b}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run('main:app',reload=True)
```

Directory:

[image]

### IIS Manager

You can check **Handler Mappings** for the respective site via IIS Manager to see that your handler is in the listing, in this example the handler would be "*fastapi_app_handler*". General Steps for deploying a website in IIS can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772350(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-use-the-ui).

[image]