# How to Deploy FastAPI web application on IIS Server?

Tags: python, iis, deployment, server, fastapi

What is the process of deploying FastAPI application on IIS? I am not using Docker container for it.

Comment: FastAPI needs a web server which implements ASGI protocol. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#installation. However you can put IIS in front as a reverse proxy, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919424/how-to-run-windows-iis-on-top-of-an-asgi-server-like-hypercorn-or-uvicorn

Comment: Python web apps on IIS should use HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this guide to deploy python on IIS: [Configure Python web apps for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019).

In addition, Microsoft no longer recommends FastCGI, it has been deprecated, so this is no longer the correct way to host Python web applications on IIS. It is recommended that you can use HttpPlatformHanlder to host.